# Xcode gtest.h not found

Tags: xcode, xcode7

I have followed the google's installation guide [here](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/XcodeGuide#Add_the_Framework_to_Your_Project).

The build fails because gtest/gtest.h is not found.

Comment: What did you add in your Bridging-Header.h file?

Comment: #include "gtest/gtest.h"

Comment: Try #include "gtest.h"

Comment: I have created a sample project and added "gtest.xcodeproj" in the sample project and created the Bridging-Header.h file and added '#include "gtest.h"' in the header file and compiled the code successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging his problem with him, we decided to go old fashioned with cmake instead of using a framework bundle, and now all is working well.